# How to run Memgraph Lab docker image?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've found Memgraph Lab as Docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/lab/tags. I've puled it using `docker pull memgraph/lab:latest`. When I try to run it using Docker Desktop I get the message that Lab is running "`2024-01-30 09:24:40 [2024-01-30 08:24:39.801] INFO: [lab] Lab is running at http://localhost:3000 in docker mode`" but when I connect to `localhost:3000` I get no response.

[image: Docker desktop]

[image: Localhost error]

I know that I can run Memgraph Lab from within Platfom using `docker run -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord-lab-only.conf` but I'd like to use this Lab only image.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the screenshot, it looks like you are using Docker Desktop. On Mac and Windows, you must add an environmental variable `QUICK_CONNECT_MG_HOST=host.docker.internal`. On Linux machines, this isn't needed.

After you start the Memggraph docker image you can ten run Memgraph Lab with

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e QUICK_CONNECT_MG_HOST=host.docker.internal memgraph/lab:latest
```